# Is the seed for a minecraft world stored in log files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing a Survival world when I found a really good seed, but today, I loaded the world in the wrong version without making a backup, and now all my progress is lost. I'm trying to find the seed for the world (/seed outputs [0]) so I can rebuild everything and I think my best bet would be in the log files. I found the log file for when I generated the world, but I couldn't find the seed, so I'm wondering if the seed is even in the log file.

Here is the log file if you want to look for yourself. (I censored out my username.) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OpNJbSLTqeAYYBNJ9mI8yOvF6cQLS6u3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You forgot to censor your UUID

Comment: I looked over your log, there is no seed there.  You might be able to use NBTedit to recover your seed.

Answer (score 3):

Try booting it up in the right version of mc and do ‘/seed’. I don’t know for sure if that will work. I tried it ten times with ten different random seeds and it only worked 6 times.

Comment: `/seed` should always work, but my world's seed showed as `0`

Comment: That is what i meant. It would either say 0 or -1000000000000000.

Answer (score 2):

This was a lost cause until I remembered that I got the seed from a minecraftforum.net post, so I went through my search history and found out that I had taken the seed from this [Minecraft Forum post](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/seeds/323332-forest-and-sunflower-plains-island-seed) and that my seed was `5738241147262227282`.

However, if it was a random seed like I originally thought, then I would've been doomed.